# how can i write bootstrap element in via javascript? the image is not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How i write bootstrap element in javascript?

This is the html code with bootstrap class

```
<div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
   <div class="portfolio-img"><img src="Images/LISTINGS IMAGES/Sobha Victoria Park.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
   <div class="portfolio-info">
      <h4>Sobha Victoria Park</h4>
      <p>Off Hennur Main Road</p>
      <a href="Images/LISTINGS IMAGES/Sobha Victoria Park.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox preview-link" title="App 1"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
      <a href="Sobha Victoria Park.html" class="details-link" title="More Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

bootstrap via javascript i written but it doesnt show correct output can anyone tell where it gone wrong. can anyone explain me how to write bootstrap class in javascript both are giving different output.

```
let card = document.createElement("div");

card.classList.add("col-lg-4");
card.classList.add("col-md-6");
card.classList.add("portfolio-item");
card.classList.add("filter-web");
let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
imgContainer.classList.add("portfolio-img");
//img tag
let image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
imgContainer.appendChild(image);
image.classList.add("img-fluid");
card.appendChild(imgContainer);
//container
let container = document.createElement("div");
container.classList.add("portfolio-info");
//product name
let name = document.createElement("h4");
name.innerText = i.productName.toUpperCase();
container.appendChild(name);

let para = document.createElement("p");
para.innerText = i.PropertyLocation.toUpperCase();
container.appendChild(para);

let anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.classList.add("portfolio-lightbox");
anchor.classList.add("preview-link");

let ivar = document.createElement("i");
ivar.classList.add("bx");
ivar.classList.add("bx-plus");
container.appendChild(ivar);
container.appendChild(anchor);


let anchorMoredetail = document.createElement("a");
anchorMoredetail.classList.add("details-link");
anchorMoredetail.classList.add("preview-link");

let ivarmoredetail = document.createElement("i");
ivarmoredetail.classList.add("bx");
ivarmoredetail.classList.add("bx-plus");

let detail = document.createElement("a");
detail.classList.add("details-link");
detail.classList.add("details-link");




container.appendChild(ivarmoredetail);
container.appendChild(anchorMoredetail);

card.appendChild(container);
console.log(card);
document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
}
```

Comment: you have white spaces in href attributes, that is wrong

Comment: you say console.log(....); method?

Comment: can anyone tell me how i write this in via javascript